# What is this attribute syntax in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, syntax, pytorch

I am current following [a tutorial in Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html) and there is this expression:

```
grad_h[h < 0] = 0
```

How does this syntax work and what does it do?

Comment: before this q is shut, it is assigning all values in the grad_h array which are less than zero to zero

Comment: if ```grad_h``` is dict and ```h = 1``` is int then: ```grad_h[h < 0] = 0``` will result in ```grad_h = {False: 0}```

Comment: This works because `grad_h` is a NumPy array.

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate of an existing question with a good answer; we just need to find it for you.

Comment: Meanwhile, here's [the relevant section in the numpy user guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing), which explains things pretty nicely.

Comment: There are probably closer duplicates (I'm still looking…), but jonrsharpe's answer to that one does a great job explaining the relevant features here.

Comment: Meanwhile, this isn't "attribute syntax". Attributes are things you access with `.`, like `self.x` or `np.sum` or `grad_h.shape`. This is _indexing_ syntax. Indexes are things you access with brackets, like `grad_h[0]` or `grad_h[0, 2]` or `grad_h[0:2, ..., 3]` or `grad_h[h < 0]`. (Technically, it's _subscripting_ syntax, which is used both for indexing and for key lookup, but nobody calls it that unless they're talking about implementing `__getitem__` methods or how the parser works…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means replace with zeros all the values in `grad_h` where its corresponding `h` is negative.

So it is implementing some kind of mask, to keep the gradient values only when `h` is negative

suppose that grad_h and h have the same shape.

```
grad_h.shape == h.shape
```

when you do `h < 0` you obtain an array of booleans of the same shape that is set to `True` if `h[i] < 0` for each i.

So then you apply this mask to do slicing on `grad_h` and finally you set all the sliced elements to zero

Comment: Can you explain how that syntax works? At a casual glance, I'd expect it to set the attribute `True` or `False` of `grad_h` to `0`…

Comment: ok I'll edit to explain better

Answer (score -2):

It means that the variable grad_h is equal to 0 as long as h is less than 0.

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your answer